# Iframe attribute onload is called many times

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe that needs to rezise it's height each time it is loaded, I tried so many examples but all of them worked fine on IE and Chrome but not FireFox, until I tried this one and it works on everything

```
function autoResize() {
            var subscriptionFrame = jQuery("#frame_name_here");
            var innerDoc = (subscriptionFrame.get(0).contentDocument) ? subscriptionFrame
                    .get(0).contentDocument
                    : subscriptionFrame.get(0).contentWindow.document;
            if (innerDoc.body.scrollHeight == 0)
                innerDoc.location.reload(true);
            subscriptionFrame.height(innerDoc.body.scrollHeight + 10);
        }

<iframe src="uploadFile.xhtml" class="upload-iframe"
            id="frame_name_here" onload="autoResize();"></iframe>
```

But there is a problem that this script calls the onload many times (recursive) , any idea why?

Comment: Because changing the height triggers the load

Comment: is it because of this: `innerDoc.location.reload(true);`?

Comment: I guess I found the problem `if (innerDoc.body.scrollHeight == 0)
                innerDoc.location.reload(true);` this part makes it reload, but the iframe height is 0 until a certain action, but this recursive call makes heavy calls to the server any idea how to stop this?

Comment: Remove `innerDoc.location.reload(true);`? Why are you doing it in the first place?

Comment: you need to reload the iframe to take the new height of the content

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this , the iframe part is displayed as none, that doesn't mean it is not in the Dom tree, that is why the recursive part happen, as the iframe in this case didn't get any height until the iframe is displayed and the content of the height is read by the resize function.So to work around this, instead of `display:none`, I made the iframe part not rendered in the dom tree until certain action, so with this action the resize method will read the content only once.